# Sprite Kit, my background image won't show on device

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, ios7.1

I have a Sprite Kit game, and a want to set the background like this:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"stars"];
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
background.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width , self.frame.size.height);

[self addChild:background];
```

This works fine on the simulator (iphone5), but on real device (iphone5 also), a big red X image appears instead of the picture.
I tried to reduce the size of the file, so it's not the biggest picture in the game (63 Kb) and still not working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The big red X means that SpriteKit could not find the image you have specified. Verify that the image is a part of the bundle, clean, delete the app from the iPhone, and then rebuild the app into the phone.

Comment: thanks, it works now. Although I still wonder why did it work on the simulator.

Comment: It is an XCode issue. Happens sometimes when some inconsistency occurs while copying a file into the bundle. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big red X means that SpriteKit could not find the image you have specified.

[image: Big Red X]

Here's what you can do to fix this:

1. Verify that the image is a part of the bundle.
2. Clean.
3. Delete the app from the device.
4. Rebuild the app into the device.

Comment: 1.5 Verify the case in filename (simulator is not case sensitive)

Comment: Often JPG WILL NOT WORK reliably in X9, change to PNG.

Comment: 2.5 delete Derived Data folder.